# Jquery Applying plugins to "display:none" elements

Tags: jquery

i am running into the same problem again,

i have some display:none elements on my site and i cant´t apply jquery plugins on them.
i am using the jScrollPane Plugin for example.
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

with:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
});
```

you can activate it, but only on visible block elements. what i am doing now is aplying it right after the display:none element has been clicked to display:block

```
$(".hidden").click(
{
    $('.hidden').show().jScrollPane();
});
```

is there a trick to make those work right away, meaning making them not ignore display:none elements?
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `display: none`, You can set them to `visibility: hidden` and `height: 0` instead and these plugins should work.

```
.element {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
}
```

Otherwise, you have to set `display: inline|block|whatever` before the plugin command is called.

Comment: yes but then i have to change height after the click too and i dont know the height before.

Comment: These plugins typically will take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try making them visible just before using the jScrollPane plugin

```
$(".hidden").click(
{   
    $(this).css('display:block');
    $(this).jScrollPane();
});
```

Comment: The correct syntax is `.css('display', 'block')` and you can just use `.show()` to get the same effect. :)

Comment: yes i forgot that in my example, i was doing that before, thx - but i was looking for a way to make it work on "none" elements from the start ;)

Comment: It has to change the display at some point, whether it does it in the plug-in or in your call doesn't really make a difference.